# Repair squeaky MDF board for a Ottoman Divan Bed

Tags: furniture, wooden-furniture, bedroom, mdf

I have an Ottoman Divan Bed that looks like this:

[image].jpg

The top part is made of MDF, unfortunately the bit where it opens on the right hand side has sunken in a little bit in the middle right. As a result the edge of the bed is very squeaky on that side and the mattress feels lower.

Whats the best way to repair this MDF without damaging the fabric? Or atleast reduce the squeaking and make the MDF flatter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDF is particularly prone to sagging, and the only way to flatten it and prevent future sagging is to a fix a  brace or batten to it.

A 1x2" piece of hardwood, as long as possible, should be used (multiple, if possible, along the width). The best way to fasten it would be with Screws through the MDF top (make sure to drill pilot holes and countersinks to prevent warping the mdf).

Im not sure about the squeaking... But if to from the top contacting the sides when you're on top, a bit of foam tape or weatherstripping in the right spot can help that.